# Is there a harmonic analysis theory for the group of strictly increasing continuous invertibe functions from $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, monotone-functions

I have very little to add to the title, would appreciate pointers to the literature. A follow up question I have is: If one considers differentiable strictly increasing functions, do they lend themselves to Lie group techniques.

Comment: Strictly increasing functions need not be invertible, so you need to explicitly include that.

Comment: You need strictly increasing, continuous, and also $f(-\infty)=-\infty$ and $f(\infty)=\infty$ to make them into a group. That group is going to be miles from local compactness, seems to me...

Comment: Continuity also does not suffice, as the function need still not be surjective.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes local compactness is at the heart of my doubt:  what more do I need to make this workable. Would it suffice to show for any such function $f$ one can define a sequence of $f_n$ with same properties that converge to $f$

Comment: None of my comments involved the extended reals. The one by David can be replaced by a statement about limits.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Got it, the function needs to be onto as well, fixing it. Thanks again.

Comment: Consider $1-1/x$ and similar.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft In fact when I wrote $f(\infty)$ I didn't mean to be talking about the extended reals, I was just using that notation as a standard abbreviation for the corresponding limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking about is the structure of the group $G$ of strictly increasing continuous surjections of $\mathbb R$ to itself, under the operation of composition..  The group is non-abelian and not countably generated.  Moreover, the subgroup generated by "typical" (in whatever sense) elements $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ will be free.

You could consider these functions as mapping the extended reals $\overline{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$ to itself, fixing $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.  Since $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is homeomorphic to a closed interval, say $I = [0,1]$, you could equivalently consider strictly increasing continuous surjections of $I$ to itself.  You could use the topology of uniform convergence on $I$, making $G$ into a metrizable topological group.  It is separable, but not locally compact and not complete. I don't think there can be anything resembling a Haar measure, so I don't know what kind of "harmonic analysis" you could have here.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. Now I have to figure out how to upvote.

Comment: Done, I had to register.

Comment: @srean You can also click on that little check mark to "accept" the answer...

Comment: Would you know of restrictions to $f$ that would make it locally compact, I do need the domain to be uncountable though.